# Avalonia создание таблиц

Tags: c#, avalonia

Подскажите, как в Avalonia сделать таблицу наподобие ListView. Я видел на GitHub'е, что ListView ещё только в планах, однако есть же способы как уже сейчас сделать подобную таблицу ?

Comment: Вопросы про Avalonia лучше задавать на английском StackOverflow с использованием тега avaloniaui. Там могут даже сами разработчики ответить.

Comment: Вместо ListView используйте DataGrid

Comment: @Vasek Я бы с удовольствием, но не как не могу его запустить. Вроде все прописал но не компилится... Буду благодарен Вам если предоставите хотя бы пустой проект с GridView что бы наконец дошло до меня как с ним жить) Из коробки не как не могу прописать... Через NuGet поставил Avalonia.Controls.DataGrid, прописал как в сети показывают, та же ситуация...

Comment: Nuget версию грида использовать не надо, она устарела. Вы видели их проект [мега пример](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone), в нем в [App.xaml](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/ControlCatalogStandalone/blob/master/ControlCatalog/App.xaml), добавляется стиль для грида. Вы добавляли этот стиль?

Comment: Спасибо большое, теперь разбирусь